# How to set a default value on a picklist from the running users User record?

Tags: formula, default-value

There are 2 fields on the Account object that users want defaulted when a new record is being created.
I was hoping to do this by setting a default value (formula) on the 2 Account fields as opposed to creating a new Flow just for that.

They want the Account custom fields to be defaulted to corresponding fields on the User records. IE: Running user creates a new Account record and the Account custom field named Sector is set to the corresponding Sector value on the running users User record.

This worked fine with the first field which is a picklist type on the Company but the default is being set from the Alias field on the User. So the default value of the Account custom field is $User.Alias and it works fine.
When I attempt to set a formula for a default on the 2nd Account Picklist field, I get a syntax error saying picklist isn't allowed (both the source and target fields are picklist types). NOTE: I do have the restrict values unchecked on the source field.
So I created a formula field on the user as text from the User picklist field and attempted to use that in the source default formula and still recieved a syntax error:
[image]

Does anyone have any thoughts on how to set this default without creating a flow? Maybe my formula is just wrong?

Comment: Are you using a Global Value Set shared by the 2 picklists? I honestly don't know if that will work, but it seems likeliest. Next thing I'd try would be `TEXT($User.Sector_Formula__c)`. Last option is `CASE($User.Sector_Formula__c),"Value 1","Value 1",:Value 2","Value 2", … "Default value")`

Comment: Hello Thomas. Thanks for the suggestions but when I use the TEXT function, I get this error: Error: Incorrect parameter type for function 'TEXT()'. Expected Number, Date, DateTime, received Text

Comment: Sorry I never updated this Thomas--the second idea worked. This is the final formula that worked: CASE($User.NVP_Sector__c, "Consumer", "Consumer",
 "Enterprise", "Enterprise",
 "Growth Equity", "Growth Equity",
 "Healthcare", "Healthcare",
 "")