# Error: Incorrect parameter type for TEXT. Expected Number, Date, DateTime, received Picklist

Tags: formula, formula-field, picklist, administration

I have a picklist custom field, let's call it Class__c of Unit custom object. I want to assign a default value to it. Default value is current user's Unit__c value. User's unit is also a picklist field.
So in Class__c field I'm using `TEXT($User.Unit__c)` but I'm getting this error:

> Error: Incorrect parameter type for TEXT. Expected Number, Date, DateTime, received Picklist

But we know that

> [TEXT converts picklist values to text in formula fields](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions_text.htm&type=5)

I'm just confused why is that happening and what can I do in this situation?

Comment: if anyone is stumbled upon this problem, I found the workaround here:
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/389886/how-to-set-a-default-value-on-a-picklist-from-the-running-users-user-record

Answer (score 1):

as mentioned below the formula editor box:

> Use formula syntax: Enclose text and picklist value API names in double quotes : ("the_text").

[image]

You can use this in your formula box. 
"$User.Unit__c"

Hope it helps :)

Comment: thank you for your answer. But actually, this is not what I meant. Actually I got the answer here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/389886/how-to-set-a-default-value-on-a-picklist-from-the-running-users-user-record

Comment: You are welcome :), but doesn't this answer your question that you posted here? You asked, why using the TEXT($User.Unit__c) is giving you the error and a fix for that right?